# FFT audio noise removal technique whining

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to remove static noise from an audio recording using the frequency domain in matlab and can't get the following to produce the audio I expect:

```
signalsamples = [...]; % n noisey signal samples
noisesamples = [...]; % isolated noise samples

signalfft = fft(signalsamples);
noisefft = fft(noisesamples, n);

reducednoisefft = signalfft ./ (noisefft * removalfactor); % Decrease the amount of noise frequencies in the signal in the frequency domain
reducednoisesamples = ifft(reducednoisefft); % Create new samples
```

When I run this the resulting audio (reducednoisesamples) has a new, loud whine much louder than anything else in the audio however you can just hear the original audio playing in the background.

1. Does this method work (or am I missing something)?
2. If it should work in theory, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your signal's FFT looks like this:

[image: signal FFT]

If your noise is a whining sound, basically a sine wave of fixed frequency, `noisefft` will look like this:

[image: noise FFT]

And so `signalfft` - which is really `signalPlusNoiseFFT` - will look like this:

[image: signal plus noise ffT]

Dividing by `noisefft` is wrong, because you'll be essentially dividing by zero where `noisefft` is weak...

You want to multiply by a function like this:

[image: desired multiplier]

Which is given by:

```
max_noise = max(noisefft)
multiplier = (max_noise - noisefft) / max_noise
```